# Program with PDFBox searching for words

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I would like to make a program that search for words in a pdf
using PDFBox.

Here is my little program:

```
List<String> words ;// List of words 
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("D:\\INIT.pdf");              
        PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
        String content = s.getText(document);
        Comparing(content,words);//methode for searching those words on my text
        System.out.println(content);
```

But is it possible to look directly into the PDF without the text with `getText`?

`getText` returns a string .in the case we have a big text in pdf File can this String bear the same text ,  is there another type to use for this case when the text is big and not supported by String ????

Comment: Even with editing, the paragraph with 'returns a string' makes no sense to me.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: And .. that word is spelled with an A - 'thank you' as opposed to 'think you'. ;)

Comment: What exactly is your problem with calling `getText`? You mention a *big text in pdf File* --- do you want to get the text in smaller portions, e.g. page-wise? You say *not supported by String* --- do you have some encoding issue? You wonder *is it possible to look directly into the PDF without the text with `getText`* --- of course you can but you will have to do almost the same as the `PDFTextStripper` does.

Comment: is That I'm forced to call (getText) to look up a word in a pdf. can I directly whether it is in the text.?? For exemple with StringTokenizer

Comment: if not. in case I have a pdf file that includes, for example 3  page , the getText method does not allow me the turning point all the text (I mean the capacity)

Comment: You can break down text retrieval to a page-wise thing: Look at the [PDFTextStripper.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.java) source code and follow the call hierarchy `getText(PDDocument)` - `writeText(PDDocument, Writer)` - `processPages(List)` - `processPage(PDPage, COSStream)` - `writePage()`. Here you are where the content of a page is assembled to one continuous text stream which then is output using `writeLine`. You can simply copy the class `PDFTextStripper` and replace `writeLine` by what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find a solution for this within PDFBox.

The whole process is rather more difficult than it seems. For example PDF text is broken into discontinuous fragments and spaces are often represented as gaps rather than space characters. There's a need both to abstract the fragments and also to retain the link between the human-readable text and the underlying fragments within the PDF. It is quite tricky.

Anyhow if you don't find a satisfactory solution within PDFBox ABCpdf will do this for you. For example the link below shows how to find and highlight keywords in a PDF.

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/8-abcpdf.operations/8-textoperation/1-methods/group.htm

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)